# Losing fluid width while copying email template from browser

Tags: html, html-email

I made this email template. But when i render it on browser and copy the result to gmail or mac mail the width fluidity is lost for the root table i think. I am using 100% width. When i resize it on browser its very fluid. Basically it gets the width of the browser window during copy. Can you please check this html to see why this happens?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Basith from Bluroe</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
     #outlook a {padding:0;}
     body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} /* force default font sizes */
     .ExternalClass {width:100%;} .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Hotmail */
     a:active, a:visited, a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] { text-decoration: none; color: #000001 !important; pointer-events: auto; cursor: default;}
     table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <table style="font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#fafafa">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-top:50px;padding-bottom:50px;">
            <table style="width:100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td style="width:500px;">
                    <table style="color:#555;font-size:14px;">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="background:#fff;padding:30px;border:1px solid #ddd;border-top-width:3px;border-top-color:#e75967;">
                            <p>Hi there,</p>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                            <p>Best,</p>
                            <p>Basith</p>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding:20px;">
                            <table style="width:100%;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>
                                    <table style="color:#555;font-size:13px;">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>
                                          <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/bluroe-labs/image/upload/v1496061160/avatar40_pmrou1.png"/>
                                          </td>
                                          <td style="padding-left:10px;">
                                            <span><b>Basith</b> <span style="color:#999;">from Bluroe</span></span>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                  <td style="text-align:right;">
                                    <a href="#" style="color:#999;font-size:13px;">Unsubscribe</a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry just wanted to understand a few things, 1. Why are you paying into Gmail? 2. I don't see a div in your code. You can take the edit suggested by @Gwesolo as well. One thing I would say is if you are pasting into Gmail then media query and things might get stripped.

Comment: sorry i didn't mean to say div. its actually a table. i changed the question.

Comment: The other question was why are you pasting into Gmail?

Comment: because i was testing on gmail and mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code and hope it helps you.

I have removed the extra 3 column table you had and added a flavor of hybrid coding to yours. If you have questions to any part of this code let me know.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Basith from Bluroe</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
     #outlook a {padding:0;}
     body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} /* force default font sizes */
     .ExternalClass {width:100%;} .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Hotmail */
     a:active, a:visited, a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] { text-decoration: none; color: #000001 !important; pointer-events: auto; cursor: default;}
     table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <table style="font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#fafafa">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top;padding:50px 0px;">
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
           <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td> 
  <![endif]--> 
  
   <div style="max-width: 500px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
  
<table style="color:#555;font-size:14px;" bgcolor="#fafafa">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="background:#fff;padding:30px;border:1px solid #ddd;border-top-width:3px;border-top-color:#e75967;text-align:left;"><p>Hi there,</p>
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software</p>
                  <p>Best,</p>
                  <p>Basith</p></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding:20px;"><table style="width:100%;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td><table style="color:#555;font-size:13px;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/bluroe-labs/image/upload/v1496061160/avatar40_pmrou1.png"/></td>
                            <td style="padding-left:10px;"><span><b>Basith</b> <span style="color:#999;">from Bluroe</span></span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table></td>
                      <td style="text-align:right;"><a href="#" style="color:#999;font-size:13px;">Unsubscribe</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

</div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>  
  <![endif]-->
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="width:500px;">
```

This line is probably the culprit as it's a fixed width and you have no CSS to make it responsive on smaller viewports.

I'd suggested creating a media query for mobile views, then a `width:100%` css class and add it to that `td`

Without any css/media queries controlling mobile views, an email client will try and render the desktop view no matter what size the screen.

Comment: im using the `width:500px` to make the content fix to the center. you can see the two empty td's before and after the content.